How to obtain the sum of all combinations of filters in Pandas?
I have a dataframe that looks like this:
Index  Name  Item  Qty
0      Anna  Rug   3
1      Anna  Rug   1
2      Anna  Box   3
3      Anna  Pen   5
4      Ted   Rug   2
5      Ted   Pen   10
6      Ted   Pen   2

And I want to obtain the sum for all combinations of Name and Item. Basically:
[[Anna, Rug, 4],
 [Anna, Box, 3],
 [Anna, Pen, 5],
 [Ted,  Rug, 2],
 [Ted,  Pen, 12]]

I only managed to do this with for loops, but it looks very inefficient and non-pythonic.

df.groupby(['Name', 'Item'], as_index=False).sum()
